Residual autocorrelation in ARMA-GARCH model
I have used the auto.arima function on my data set, which is the Ethereum-USD exchange rate, and I end up with an ARMA(2,2) model based on the AIC. I have estimated the first difference of the logs, and found that we have ARCH effects, and serially uncorrelated errors from my ARMA(2,2) model on the differenced data. I then fitted an ARMA(2,2)+GARCH(1,1) model by using:
garch_eth_model_AIC <- ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder=c(2,2)),
                              variance.model = list(model="sGARCH", garchOrder=c(1,1)),
                              distribution.model = "std")

I then fitted it to my differenced data and got the following output:
arma_garch_model_AIC <- ugarchfit(spec = garch_eth_model_AIC, data = na.omit(ETH_FD), solver = "gosolnp"):
*---------------------------------*
*          GARCH Model Fit        *
*---------------------------------*

Conditional Variance Dynamics   
-----------------------------------
GARCH Model : sGARCH(1,1)
Mean Model  : ARFIMA(2,0,2)
Distribution    : std 

Optimal Parameters
------------------------------------
        Estimate  Std. Error     t value Pr(>|t|)
mu      0.006011    0.000498     12.0577 0.000000
ar1     0.592644    0.010762     55.0663 0.000000
ar2     0.404551    0.011505     35.1641 0.000000
ma1    -0.671385    0.000064 -10410.7217 0.000000
ma2    -0.318471    0.002838   -112.2196 0.000000
omega   0.000156    0.000061      2.5324 0.011328
alpha1  0.116136    0.032568      3.5659 0.000363
beta1   0.858063    0.033880     25.3265 0.000000
shape   3.168304    0.294769     10.7484 0.000000

Robust Standard Errors:
        Estimate  Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)
mu      0.006011    0.000856     7.0186 0.000000
ar1     0.592644    0.009298    63.7383 0.000000
ar2     0.404551    0.009421    42.9415 0.000000
ma1    -0.671385    0.000073 -9175.3800 0.000000
ma2    -0.318471    0.003426   -92.9526 0.000000
omega   0.000156    0.000068     2.2826 0.022452
alpha1  0.116136    0.033929     3.4229 0.000620
beta1   0.858063    0.038428    22.3292 0.000000
shape   3.168304    0.283702    11.1677 0.000000

LogLikelihood : 2518.954 

Information Criteria
------------------------------------
                    
Akaike       -3.3157
Bayes        -3.2840
Shibata      -3.3157
Hannan-Quinn -3.3039

Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Residuals
------------------------------------
                         statistic  p-value
Lag[1]                       7.489 0.006208
Lag[2*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][11]    14.236 0.000000
Lag[4*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][19]    17.914 0.002691
d.o.f=4
H0 : No serial correlation

Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Squared Residuals
------------------------------------
                        statistic p-value
Lag[1]                     0.3434  0.5579
Lag[2*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][5]    4.2916  0.2199
Lag[4*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][9]    6.4937  0.2454
d.o.f=2

Weighted ARCH LM Tests
------------------------------------
            Statistic Shape Scale P-Value
ARCH Lag[3]    0.7836 0.500 2.000 0.37603
ARCH Lag[5]    6.1733 1.440 1.667 0.05468
ARCH Lag[7]    6.5783 2.315 1.543 0.10686

Nyblom stability test
------------------------------------
Joint Statistic:  2.0289
Individual Statistics:             
mu     0.0792
ar1    0.1387
ar2    0.1422
ma1    0.1666
ma2    0.1786
omega  0.4541
alpha1 0.4921
beta1  0.5360
shape  0.9402

Asymptotic Critical Values (10% 5% 1%)
Joint Statistic:         2.1 2.32 2.82
Individual Statistic:    0.35 0.47 0.75

Sign Bias Test
------------------------------------
                   t-value   prob sig
Sign Bias          1.46093 0.1442    
Negative Sign Bias 0.89777 0.3694    
Positive Sign Bias 0.09511 0.9242    
Joint Effect       3.23377 0.3570    


Adjusted Pearson Goodness-of-Fit Test:
------------------------------------
  group statistic p-value(g-1)
1    20     23.09       0.2332
2    30     26.26       0.6113
3    40     49.59       0.1191
4    50     45.38       0.6207


Elapsed time : 0.5222051 

Why does the Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Residuals indicate that we have serially correlated residuals, when the ARMA(2,2) model did not? Is there a remedy to this problem?
When I tried using BIC in the auto.arima function, it returned a (0,0) model on the differenced data. When combining the models again to a ARMA(0,0)+GARCH(1,1) I do not face the problem of serially correlated residuals.
This is my first question here, so if there is something lacking in order to give a helpful response don't hesitate to point it out!

Please use capital letters where appropriate. Also, AIC is "An Information Criterion" (later called "Akaike's Information Criterion"), so you do not have to say "AIC information criterion"; AIC is sufficient. Similarly with BIC.
